# How do I migrate an Ubuntu installation to a home folder partition?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, home-directory

I have two partitions of Ubuntu installed on my Samsung N150 Plus. One is 11.04 (90GB) and one is 11.10 (60GB). All my documents are on the 11.04 home folder, but they are too big to cut and paste into 11.10.

I would like to remove the OS from 11.04 and use that partition as my home folder in 11.10. Any easy step-by-step guide on how to do this would be appreciated.

NOTE: I have a cracked screen, and cannot always see what's on the screen of my Samsung; nothing displays on my external monitor until I've already booted.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** one important step was missing.

The following procedure should work:

1. Remove the system files of 11.04 (**warning**: this will remove all programs and data that are not in your home folder)

   a. In 11.10, open a terminal

   b. Run `sudo nautilus`

   c. Mount the 11.04 partition

   d. Delete everything except your home folder from that partition
2. Update grub

   a. Now, run `sudo update-grub`

   b. Reboot
3. If you have any files in the 11.10 home, move it to the other partition (the one that was 11.04)
4. Move the personal folders to the partition root. In the partition that will be your home folder, you need to move the folders to the partition root. If you have /media/DISK-ID/home/user, you need to move it to /media/DISK-ID/user.

   a. Open a terminal and run `cd /media/YOUR-DISK-ID/home`

   b. Move everything from here to the parent folder: `sudo mv * ..`

   c. Remove the empty home folder: `cd .. ; sudo rmdir home`
5. Update you `fstab`

   a. Run `sudo df -h`

   b. See the partition name of the your new home (it must be something like `/dev/sdaX` where X is a number)

   c. Run `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

   d. Add the following line to it:

   `/dev/sdaX /home           ext4    defaults        0       0`

   e. Reboot

Comment: I have done 1 it came up with "** (nautilus:1824): DEBUG: Syncdaemon not running, waiting for it to start in NameOwnerChanged
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.", but, I was able to delete all, except the home folder. I was able to do number 2, no problem there.

Comment: 3 I wasn't able to do as it say's i haven't enough space. I have 95Gb with 72Gb home folder.

Comment: About #1: it's only a nautilus warning, no worry here. About #3: do you have 95 GB of files and the home partition has 72 GB?

Comment: Its 95Gb with 72Gb of files. Properties says this, but has no available space

Comment: The home folder in 11.10 uses how many GB?

Comment: its 4.3kb there are 2 icons in there desktop and a folder called examples.

Comment: I think we misunderstood. In #3, I mean "if you have any file in your 11.10 home, move it to the other partition". In your case, you don't have any files in the new Ubuntu version, right?

Comment: Yes except the 2 icons in there, an icon called desktop and a folder called examples

Comment: You don't need to move these things. Go to next step. Please, note that I've added a new step that is now #4.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the 11.04 installation is quite simple. You'll just log onto 11.10, mount the root filesystem of the other installation and delete everything except the home directory. Then you'll edit your grub menu to not include it. Afterwards, you can copy your data from the home folder of 11.10 onto the one from 11.04, and then use that filesystem as a home folder in 11.10.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I had tried to delete everything from the 11.04 partition. But there is no, delete or move to Rubbish bin.. so I cannot delete them....any help on how to delete....I'll do the grub thing, when I have done the home partition thing...thanks again